# Can i pass php variables when including a partial?

Tags: javascript, php, twig, partials, octobercms

I am new to OctoberCMS so I don't know a lot of things.
I read the October documentation and i know how to pass variables when using partials in the static way:

```
{% partial "location" city="Vancouver" country="Canada" %}
```

My problem is that I need to use php or js variables. Let's say I have an input field where the user writes an ID, then after a button is pressed I want to pass the ID to a partial. I am trying to do something like this :

```
{% partial "location" city=$city country=$country %}
```

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this method as documented here? https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/partials#partial-variables

```
{% partial "location" city=city country=country %}
```

EDIT

As an aside, you need to define your page variables in the onStart function.

```
url = "/blah"
layout = "default"
==
<?
function onStart()
{
    $this['country'] = ...;
    $this['city'] = ...;
}
?>
==
{% partial "location" city=city country=country %}
```

<strike>EDIT</strike>

Have you read the section on AJAX? https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/introduction

More specifically - https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/update-partials#pushing-updates AND https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/update-partials#update-definition

EDIT

Just re-read your original question and you're asking about binding to form elements, not AJAX.

Take a look at the JS API - https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api#javascript-api

I think you could do something like:

`<form onsubmit="$(this).request('onMyProcessingMethod'); return false;">`

```
$('form').request('onMyProcessingMethod', {
    update: {myPartialName: '.whereIWantTheOutputToGo'},
    data: {country: 'Canada'} // Not 100% sure how to access form input; maybe ID selector
})
```

Comment: Yes but country should be a twig variable in this case and i don't know how to use them, i tried but with no results.

Comment: According to the blub at the bottom of this page ("Access logic" - https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/templating), Twig should be able to access PHP variables; without the dollar sign of course.

Comment: Right before calling your partial, try to output a variable and see if it displayed - {{ country }}

Comment: thank you, it's working but what if i want to change the variable? i read that i must use the onStart() but now i am using an ajax form to determine the value so it can't work. Should i use a normal form with post? or do you have a better solution?

Comment: I think maybe this is the wrong way to achieve that thing, maybe you have to look to components instead of partials

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables inside the partial in this way:

```
<p>Country: {{ country }}, city: {{ city }}.</p>
```

Comment: Yes, but the OP needs to pass the variables to the partial before he can access them there.

Comment: There is a dedicated function onStart() which helps us to define variables before the script can access them.